# Multiple Jenkins workspace using single .git dir (--separate-git-dir )

Tags: git, jenkins

How can I improve disk space utilization and build time, making all my git jenkins jobs use one .git dir

workspace/.git
workspace/develop-ci
workspace/feature-ci
etc

I know I can use **--separate-git-dir** but I'm not sure how.

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Jenkins Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) has an option to set **reference**. It acts exactly like the `--reference` of [git clone](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html). You should create one reference dir (with full .git directory), and all jobs should point there. (If you will look at thoses jobs, the .git directory will be very small).

Please note that it saves space during **first clone**. If you want to make sure that also future update to the repository will be only in one place, you need to explicitly update the reference place (if manually run `git fetch`), and then run `git gc` in all other places. All of this could be automated of course by writing Jenkins jobs to do that.